# Ec2-describe-snapshots results to file on anything older than 7 days?

Tags: amazon-ec2, robocopy

I want to delete ec2 snapshots that are older than 7 days. I can create a txt file of all available snapshots using ec2-describe-snapshots, but I'm having trouble pulling the old snapshots from that file.

Here is a typical line from the txt file:

SNAPSHOT   snap-2031781c   vol-e0b9c189    completed   2013-10-13T18:45:19+0000    100%    572608710214    100 Created
 by CreateImage(i-72a6d046) for ami-eace57da from vol-e0b9c189

All of my systems are Windows 7/2008/2012. I tried using this script from another post without luck:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('robocopy "%cd%" "%temp%" * /minage:7 /l /np /fp /njh /njs /ndl /ns^|findstr /riv /c:"^$" /c:"\aws\working\AllSnapShots.txt"') > c:\aws\working\Remove-Snaps.txt
```